# QT function templates

Tags: c++, qt, templates

How can I use function templates so that the following method works for any passed vector?

```
class MyClass  
{  
public:  
    static void method(Vector &aVector);  
};  

void MyClass::method(Vector &aVector)  
{  
...  
}
```

I tried the following, but I get this error message:
**collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    template<class T>
    static void method(Vector &aVector);

};

template<class T>
void MyClass::method(Vector &aVector) {
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<class T> static void method(Vector<T> &aVector);
```

Comment: (whispering:) please write vector with a small v :)

Comment: This is the correct answer for the problem, are you sure you're using this code?  Is it a std::vector<T> or a custom `Vector` class of your own?  If it's your own the problem may be in the custom `Vector` class itself - which is why everyone uses the proven library one.

Comment: And don't forget to actually include the header for the vector class and to activate the std namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare the function as a template, and pass its template parameter to the vector, like so:

```
class MyClass  
{  
public:  
    template<class T>
    static void method(Vector<T> &aVector)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I found that this error ocured when my program did not clear from memory properly. I.e. there was an instance of my program running. Picked it up on my windows based pc. so ctrl + alt + del and you should see an instance of "collect2.exe" or something running. Ending that task and running should work.

Not sure why this happens.